# Safely serialize Text to Bytestring

Tags: haskell

The text package does not provide an instance of `Binary` to encode/decode text. I have read about and understand the reasoning behind this (namely, `Text` should be encoding-agnostic). However, I need a `Binary` instance of `Text`. I've found that there is a package called text-binary that does this. However, the instance is as follows:

```
instance Binary T.Text where
    put = put . T.encodeUtf8
    get = T.decodeUtf8 <$> get
```

Pretty good, except that `decodeUtf8` is a partial function, so I'd rather be using `decodeUtf8'` and passing the failure through the `Get` monad. I can't figure out how to fail correctly with the `Get` monad. Just from looking around in Data.Binary.Get, I see this:

```
data Decoder a = Fail !B.ByteString {-# UNPACK #-} !ByteOffset String
          | Partial (Maybe B.ByteString -> Decoder a)
          | Done !B.ByteString {-# UNPACK #-} !ByteOffset a
```

Which seems to indicate that there is a way to do what I want. I just can't see how the library authors intend for it to be used. I appreciate any insights that a more learned mind than my own has to offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, though we tend to disregard it, the `Monad` class still has that yucky `fail` method:

```
   get = do
      utf8'd <- get 
      case T.decodeUtf8' utf8'd of
         Just t  -> return t
         Nothing -> fail "No parse for UTF-8 Text"
```

I'm not sure if it should still be considered "correct" to use `fail`, but it seems to be the obvious thing for a case like this. I suppose even if it's removed from the `Monad` class, there'll be some other `class MonadPlus m => MonadFail m where fail :: String -> m a` which `Get` will be an instance of.

Comment: I'm normally opposed to using `fail`, but I looked up how it's defined for `Get`, and it does have a legitimate definition (One that doesn't crash the program). I would never call fail for an unknown monad, but since I am certain of how fail is defined here, I'm fine with it. Also, just for the benefit of future readers, I'll mention that `decodeUtf8'` returns a `Either`, not a `Maybe`, so the pattern matching you did should actually use `Left` and `Right` instead.